# How to add link title in combine field filter

Tags: entities, views, navigation

my view having combine field filter.it is working based on link field. the link field title is "test" and the url is "http://example.com".when i search using "test" it is not showing any result.if i search using "example" it shows correct content.how add the title also in combine field filter. anybodys can help? thanks advance!.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Add both link field title and link field url as fields in the views.
- If you don't need title field, please  check "exclude from display".
- Then try searching using the content of title field(in your example. "test")

Comment: the field name is like developer. i already added developer field in views. that field is link type. so it have title and url

Comment: add two field of same name (i.e: developer). Select the format as "title as plain text" for one and "link as URL" for another.then hide the field of format "title as plain text"  . let me know if this works.

Comment: i need a solution without other extra field

Comment: you can exclude the field from display, in that way end userwill never know that the field is added in the view.